# TxPool on Ganache

Tags: json-rpc, ganache, txpool

I started using Ganache to run Ethereum and tried via cURL the following:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"txpool_status","params":[],"id":1}' http://ip:port
```

But I got the message:

> Method txpool_status not supported

Is there a way to enable TxPool in Ganache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a [recent issue on Sep 16th, 2019](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core/issues/484#issue-494312691):

> `ganache-core` does not currently support a mempool, although [this WIP](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core/blob/a4e8989efc301b28d094082297dfbb1c4b25a744/src/ledgers/ethereum/components/transaction-pool.ts#L80-L87) refactor by @davidmurdoch does support a mempool to some degree

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Is there a way to do so in the AppImage?